# jquery mobile moving all sliders toogether

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm trying to do a simple shoes size converter.
i have update all the sliders value accordingly and i know how to get their values but i want to be able to update on change event the sliders all together.

How can i do it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQM Demo 1</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="mens" data-add-back-btn="true">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Men's Size</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <form action="#" method="get">
            <label for="europe" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Europe:</label>
            <input type="range" name="europe" id="europe" value="38" min="38" max="47" step="0.5" data-highlight="true" data-theme="b" data-track-theme="c" orientation="vertical"/>
            <label for="us" class="ui-hidden-accessible">USA:</label>
            <input type="range" name="us" id="us" value="5.5" min="5.5" max="12.5" step="0.5" data-highlight="true" data-theme="b" data-track-theme="c" orientation="vertical"/>

            <label for="uk" class="ui-hidden-accessible">UK:</label>
            <input type="range" name="uk" id="uk" value="5" min="5" max="12" step="0.5" data-highlight="true" data-theme="b" data-track-theme="c" orientation="vertical" />

            <label for="japan" class="ui-hidden-accessible">JAPAN:</label>
            <input type="range" name="japan" id="japan" value="23.5" min="23.5" max="30.5" step="0.5" data-highlight="true" data-theme="b" data-track-theme="c" orientation="vertical" />
        </form>
    </div>

<script>
    var self = this;
    this.sliderTouchUp = function() {
        var currentVal = $('#europe').val();
        console.log("val change to " + currentVal);
    };
    $('.ui-slider').live('mouseup', self.sliderTouchUp);
    $('.ui-slider').live('touchend', self.sliderTouchUp);

</script>

<div data-role="footer">

</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do it, test it please and tell me is this what you wanted all along:

```
   $("input#europe, input#us, input#uk, input#japan").live("slidestop", function() {
       $(this).mouseup();
       var changeVal = ($(this).val() - $(this).attr('min'))/($(this).attr('max') - $(this).attr('min'));
       changeSliders(changeVal, $(this).attr('id'));    
   });

   function changeSliders(changeVal, sliderID){
       $("input#europe, input#us, input#uk, input#japan").each(function(){
           var newValue = parseFloat($(this).attr('min')) + parseFloat(($(this).attr('max') - $(this).attr('min')))*changeVal;
           if($(this).attr('id') != sliderID) { 
               $(this).val(newValue);
           }
       });
       $("input#europe, input#us, input#uk, input#japan").slider('refresh');    
   }
```

You can add as much sliders you want, you just need to add/remove elements here:

```
$("input#europe, input#us, input#uk, input#japan")
```

Also at the same place in the function.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/PzTeX/) is a live example.

Comment: @Gajotres *Please do not* beg/encourage people to accept or vote for your answers.

Comment: @AndrewBarber stop bugging people who ask for the most normal thing, there is absolutely nothing wrong about remidnign peopole of this option. Let the PO express hisself if he is annoyed, stop speaking for them. read here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69775/remind-new-users-to-choose-some-answers

Comment: To be honest I don't care any more, few points more or less became insignificant to me.