# Taking a value from a jQuery Mobile Slider and setting it on another slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to take a value from a jQuery mobile slider after dragging it a bit and then setting it to another jQuery mobile slider programmatically.

I've tried `$(selector).slider(value)`, `$(selector).attr('value)`, or `$(selector).slider().value()` but they all don't seem to work in my case.

I'm using jQuery Mobile 1.2.0 and jQuery 1.8.0

Below is the code that I'm trying to get to work:

```
$('#slider1').change(function(){
        var slide1Val = $(this).val();
        $('#slider2').val(slide1Val).slider('refresh');
};
```

[Here's the actual URL that I'm trying to work on](http://jsfiddle.net/b3bJr/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this

```
$("#gen1").live("pageinit",function(){
     $("#slider1").change(function(){
         $("field1").html(this.value);
         $("#slider2").val(this.value/2);
         $("#slider2").slider("refresh");
   });
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: You can find a fiddle here jsfiddle.net/YemGJ/1. However,your code is correct and working fine . Please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: This one makes a lot of sense. Played around with that fiddle but it doesn't seem to integrate in my code very well. Here's the fiddle for my code http://jsfiddle.net/b3bJr/5/

Comment: you can find the working fiddle for your code here http://jsfiddle.net/b3bJr/7/  I have added the change event in the 'pageinit' of "gen1".This will ensure the div is good before you execute anything on it. Hope this helps

Comment: thanks! you really helped out a lot! However, isn't the live method already deprecated and replaced with on? But it works! :D

Comment: Glad to be at some assistance.Very true .live() is deprecated and should be replaced with .on().To be frank, I am still trying to figure out how to correctly use it.I found a good question about it :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9451814/how-to-attach-a-event-to-a-jquery-mobile-page-using-on-and-off

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/PzTeX/

That example was created for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13554192/1848600

I made it a month ago. Basically it moves 3 other sliders according to the first one, this is a code example:

```
$("input#europe, input#us, input#uk, input#japan").live("slidestop", function() {
    $(this).mouseup();
    var changeVal = ($(this).val() - $(this).attr('min'))/($(this).attr('max') - $(this).attr('min'));
    changeSliders(changeVal, $(this).attr('id'));    
});

function changeSliders(changeVal, sliderID){
    $("input#europe, input#us, input#uk, input#japan").each(function(){
    var newValue = parseFloat($(this).attr('min')) + parseFloat(($(this).attr('max') - $(this).attr('min')))*changeVal;
    if($(this).attr('id') != sliderID) {    
        $(this).val(newValue);
    }
    });
    $("input#europe, input#us, input#uk, input#japan").slider('refresh');    
}
```